# Retrieve data from SQL Server stored procedure into an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to get data from my database and put it into an array.

I tried this code :

```
DataClassesDataContext DS = new DataClassesDataContext();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> _news = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        _news.Add(DS.select_top_five_news().ElementAt(i).ToString());
    }
}
```

but it returns nothing of what I want and gives me this error :

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index

And this is the stored procedure I use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_top_five_news
AS  
   RETURN 
       SELECT top 5 * 
       FROM news 
       ORDER BY newsid DESC
```

The problem is that the stored procedure's result is returned as a *single* result and I *need to loop into* it to get each individual record

Any help please! Or another way does the same goal?

Comment: You're not populating the data inside DS before attempting to get information from it

Comment: and how to populate the data?

Answer (score 0):

Since your procedure is already filtering the data for you, you should just have to do the following.  Your procedure will return up to 5 results, so whatever you've received is what you're getting.  If you need default entities, you'll have to loop over and add the missing items, not pull the existing items out of your results.

```
DataClassesDataContext DS = new DataClassesDataContext();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var _news = DS.select_top_five_news().ToList();
}
```

If you were using an entity directly you'd do this.

```
DataClassesDataContext DS = new DataClassesDataContext();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var _news = DS.News.OrderBy(n => n.ID).Take(5).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I need to get each individual record of the five record retrieved

Comment: Both statements will work, assuming you have 5 records in your news table.  Based on what you've given us, if you aren't receiving 5 records its because you don't have 5 records.  You've shortcutted your stored procedure's results, if you provide the desired columns I can taylor the answer.

Comment: the problem is that the sp's result is returned as a single result and I need to loop into it to get each individual record

Comment: What do you see being returned from DS.select_top_five_news()?  You should see something similar to ObjectResult<select_top_five_news_result>.  This is a collection that will contain one entity for every record returned from your procedure.  You do not need to manually loop over it.  Entity Framework will parse the results for you as long as your procedure has been correctly imported.